# How to find nth fibonacci term in prolog?

Tags: prolog, fibonacci

Here's the code that i've written:

```
/* fib(X,Y) means xth term in fibonacci series is Y. */

fib(1,0).                     
fib(2,1).
fib(X,Y):-X1 is X-1,fib(X1,Y1),X2 is X-2,fib(X2,Y2),Y=Y1+Y2.

?-fib(6,X).
X = 1+0+1+(1+0)+(1+0+1) .
```

Why am I getting the result as a summation series? What corrections should I make?

Comment: `Y is Y1+Y2` as you did for other arithmetics

Comment: `=/2` is the unifcation operator that unifies terms. It does not evaluate arithmetic expressions, unless you're using one of those odd-ball Prologs like Visual Prolog, Turbo Prolog, or PDC Prolog (all the same thing).

Answer (score 0):

You are doing summation using + sign, when it should be "is". In prolog, the correct code will be:

```
fib(1,0).                     
fib(2,1).
fib(X,Y):-X1 is X-1,fib(X1,Y1),X2 is X-2,fib(X2,Y2),Y is Y1+Y2.
```